# .net XMLSerializer multiple namespace problem

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I've got a problem using the .net XMLSerializer object and XML namespaces. My experience of the the XMLSerializer is very limited and I haven't worked with XML much before. I'm trying to something like the following:

```
<Record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <Property1>blah</Property1> 
  <oai_dc:dc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">>
    <dc:Property2>asdsd</dc:Property2> 
    <dc:Property3>asdasasdda</dc:Property3> 
  </oai_dc:dc>
</Record>
```

however the best I can get at the moment is (note the position of the namespace declarations)

```
<Record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <Property1>blah</Property1> 
    <oai_dc:dc>
      <dc:Property2>asdsd</dc:Property2> 
      <dc:Property3>asdasasdda</dc:Property3> 
  </oai_dc:dc>
</Record>
```

The namespaces are being declared in the root element, not on the dc element as I would like. I understand from that either declaring the namespace in the root or the element that uses the namespace should be acceptable.

I'm attaching the XMLSerializerNamespaces as follows:

```
Dim XMLNamespaces As New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
        XMLNamespaces.Add("oai_dc", "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/")
        XMLNamespaces.Add("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")
        XMLNamespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

XMLSerializer.Serialize(XMLWriter, inputObject, XMLNamespaces)
```

and the objects I'm using are shown below:

```
<XmlRoot("Record")> _
Public Class Record

    <XmlElement("Property1")> _
    Public Property1 As String

    <XmlElement("dc", Namespace:="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/")> _
    Public DCMetadata As DublinCore

    Public Sub New()
        DCMetadata = New DublinCore()
    End Sub

End Class


<XmlRoot("dc", Namespace:="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/")> _
Public Class DublinCore

    <XmlElement("Property2", Namespace:="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")> _
    Public Property2 As String

    <XmlElement("Property3", Namespace:="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")> _
    Public Property3 As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Is there any way to force the XMLSerializer to output the namespace declarations against an element further down the tree?

Thanks for any input,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I now think the existing solution is valid for my requirements, there is a way to achieve what I need.

Declare an XmlSerializerNamespaces object within the class to be serialized.

```
<XmlNamespaceDeclarations()> _
    Public xmlns As XmlSerializerNamespaces
```

Then add the namespaces to this collection instead of attaching it to the serializer directly. This has the desired effect of declaring the namespace where it is used.

```
xmlns = New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
        xmlns.Add("oai_dc", "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/")
        xmlns.Add("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/")
        xmlns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
```

Andrew